# Snowflake:Read all files with wildcard

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement is to read all files from the S3 bucket starting with same name

[image]

Tried below it didn't work out

```
with s3 as  (
  select  $1 as json_array
  from '@stage/airflow/reponse__2022-06-06_05*'
  (file_format => 'public.S3_JSON')
)
select f.value,f.value:CompanyId
from s3, Table(Flatten(s3.json_array)) f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pattern:

```
with s3 as  (
  select  $1 as json_array
  from @stage
  (file_format => 'public.S3_JSON',
   pattern => 'airflow/reponse__2022-06-06_05.*')
)
select f.value,f.value:CompanyId
from s3, Table(Flatten(s3.json_array)) f;
```

More: [Querying Data in Staged Files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html)

> PATTERN => 'regex_pattern'
>
> A regular expression pattern string, enclosed in single quotes, specifying the file names and/or paths on the external stage to match.

Comment: I tried pattern , it didn't pull records

Comment: ``` select  $1 as json_array
  from '@STAGE/airflow/'
  (file_format => 'public.S3_JSON',
      pattern => 'reponse__2022-06-06.*')```

Comment: @Karthik That's a different path than originally provided in the question.  Have you tried: `from @stage
  (file_format => 'public.S3_JSON',
   pattern => 'airflow/reponse__2022-06-06_05.*')
)`